# Use gettext in <%= link ..%>

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to use `gettext` to i18n an application. I don't yet understand how I can use it within `link`. How can I translate the "Show" link text and the `[confirm: "Are you sure?"]` part?

```
<%= link "Show", to: user_path(@conn, :show, user), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
<%= link "Edit", to: user_path(@conn, :edit, user), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
<%= link "Delete", to: user_path(@conn, :delete, user), 
method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], 
class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have `import YourApp.Gettext` in `YourApp.Web.view/0`, just wrap each piece of text you want to translate in a call to `gettext/1`:

```elixir
<%= link gettext("Show"), to: user_path(@conn, :show, user), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
<%= link gettext("Edit"), to: user_path(@conn, :edit, user), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
<%= link gettext("Delete"), to: user_path(@conn, :delete, user), 
method: :delete, data: [confirm: gettext("Are you sure?")], 
class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
```